# Passing parameters to modules in dev and prod clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Hi how should i pass the variable to only one environment.

I have a logging parameter defined and i want to pass this variable only to my prod redshift and not to the dev redshift. The dev redshift cluster should not have logging parameter defined.

I am stuck on how to pass inside a module, i have separate modules for prod and dev redshift cluster.

```
variable "logging" {
     target_bucket= "xxxx"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket}-${var.env}"
  logging = ["${var.logging}"]


module "redshift-dev" {
  source                      = "../modules/xxxx"
  env                         = "dev"
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  logging                     = {}

module "redshift-prod" {
  source                      = "../modules/xxxx"
  env                         = "prod"
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  logging                     = {
     target_bucket= "xxxx"
}
```

Comment: Can you show your module definition as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you misunderstood on how to manage different environments with terraform modules.

Don't write two modules to manage dev/prod environment, one should be enough.

```
variable "logging" {
     target_bucket= "xxxx-${var.env}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket}-${var.env}"
  logging = ["${var.logging}"]


module "redshift" {
  source                      = "../modules/xxxx"
  env                         = "${var.env}"
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  logging                     = ${var.env == "prod" ? {} : { target_bucket= "xxxx" } }"
}
```

The key point to manage the different setting for different environments  in this case is using terraform [Conditionals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals).

```
The conditional syntax is the well-known ternary operation:

CONDITION ? TRUEVAL : FALSEVAL
```

Comment: They would be much better off making the logging parameter an optional one (`default = ""`) and handling it in the module instead. This would create a much better interface to the module but it's hard to properly recommend this because they haven't shown their module code.